# How do I parse a JSON array in Java?

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON text and would like to get the values "detest" and "dislike".

```
{
  "noun": {
    "syn": [
      "hatred",
      "emotion"
    ],
    "ant": [
      "love"
    ]
  },
  "verb": {
    "syn": [
      "detest",
      "dislike"
    ],
    "ant": [
      "love"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried parsing it using the org.json library with the following:

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONObject(String);
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("syn");
```

But I can't seem to access the array this way.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your actual code that reproduces the problem and explain how specifically it is not working for you. Parsing JSON in Java is a topic that is covered repeatedly and extensively in numerous places, I would very highly suggest you do a cursory search and look at a few tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is related to the [JSON.simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) library.

---

You need a `JSONParser` instance to get a `JSONObject` value from your `String` object.

```
JSONObject data;
try {
    JSONParser helper = new JSONParser();
    data = (JSONObject)helper.parse(String);
} catch (ParseException parse) {
    // Invalid syntax
    return;
}
// Note that these may throw several exceptions
JSONObject node = (JSONObject)data.get("verb");
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)node.get("syn");
```